# trac wiki suddenly failing on logins

Tags: sqlite, wiki, trac

I have a trac wiki that seems to have decided not to allow logins. Selecting "login" does not even get users to the text boxes that allow them to enter their login details. Instead there seems to be a timeout, after which the browser presents the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/api.py", line 436, in send_error
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/chrome.py", line 803, in render_template
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/api.py", line 212, in __getattr__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/main.py", line 298, in _get_session
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/session.py", line 162, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/session.py", line 183, in get_session
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/web/session.py", line 62, in get_session
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/db/util.py", line 65, in execute
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/db/sqlite_backend.py", line 78, in execute
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/db/sqlite_backend.py", line 56, in execute
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/trac/db/sqlite_backend.py", line 48, in _rollback_on_error
OperationalError: database is locked
```

The sqlite database seems to remain locked for the duration of this login attempt. I did try rebuilding the database with something like :

```
echo .dump | sqlite3 existing.db | sqlite3 new.db
```

but the problem persists. We are running this using the web server rather than tracd. Any ideas how to fix this, or how to extract the wiki pages and rebuild user logins around them? I'm running on CentOS. This is puzzling to me since things just suddenly seem to have stopped working, and trac is not really my main area of expertise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, and figured out a better way to proceed in future. I made a copy of the database :

```
$ cp /var/www/trac/db/trac.db ./new.db
```

I then made a list of the tables in the database by issuing the .schema
command and parsing it :

```
$ echo .schema | sqlite3 new.db | grep "CREATE TABLE" | awk '{ print $3 }' > tableList.new
```

The file tableList.new then listed the tables :

```
attachment
auth_cookie
cache
component
enum
milestone
node_change
permission
report
repository
revision
session
session_attribute
system
ticket
ticket_change
ticket_custom
version
wiki
```

After poking around in the database, it seemed like the problem was likely in
the tables auth_cookie, session_attribute, session, simply because they seemed
likely to have something to do with logging in. So, I decided to drop those
tables and re-create them. First I dumped all the schemas in the database
on a table-by-table basis :

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/rm -rf newSchemas
mkdir -p newSchemas

while read tn
do

 echo New $tn
 echo ".schema $tn" | sqlite3 new.db > newSchemas/$tn\.sql

done < tableList.new

exit 0
```

Then I dropped the tables and recreated them as empty tables for those three
tables :

```
#!/bin/bash

cp -v new.db fix.db
echo "DROP TABLE auth_cookie;" | sqlite3 fix.db
echo "DROP TABLE session_attribute;" | sqlite3 fix.db
echo "DROP TABLE session;" | sqlite3 fix.db

cat newSchemas/auth_cookie.sql | sqlite3 fix.db
cat newSchemas/session.sql | sqlite3 fix.db
cat newSchemas/session_attribute.sql | sqlite3 fix.db

exit 0
```

So, those three tables were there, but empty, in the new database.

I then put the fixed database in place :

```
$ /bin/mv -vf /var/www/trac/db/trac.db /var/www/trac/db/trac.db.Save
$ /bin/mv fix.db /var/www/trac/db/trac.db
```

And logins started working.

Other things I learned - in addition to dumping the schemas, you can dump the
actual SQL to create the tables with data :

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/rm -rf newTables
mkdir -p newTables

while read tn
do

 echo New $tn
 echo ".dump $tn" | sqlite3 new.db > newTables/$tn\.sql

done < tableList.new

exit 0
```

That might allow you to see if any tables have errors in them.

And you can check on your database integrity :

```
$ echo "PRAGMA integrity_check;" | sqlite3 new.db
ok
```

You can even dump the whole database and re-create it :

```
$ echo .dump | sqlite3 existing.db  | sqlite3 fromDump.db
```

The big thing, though, is that copying the *.db tables around only works if
the database is not being accessed. Really, you should do a backup with :

```
$ trac-admin /var/www/trac hotcopy /var/www/tracBackup
```

For that to work, the directory /var/www/tracBackup should not exist (it will
be created). This locks the database for the duration of the copy. You then
back up /var/www/tracBackup and restore from that. The only reason I went in
and mucked with the database is that I did not know that.